# for_each и unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

Имеется список `unique_ptr`. Можно ли, используя `for_each` пройтись по списку. Лямда в которую передаю элемент списка:

```
auto researchRespawns = [&](Tank& tank)
```

Ошибка:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<Tank>' to 'Tank &'
```

Я понимаю в чём дело, надо бы разыменовать элемент, но можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Передавайте ссылку на умный указатель и используйте её внутри лямбда-выражения:

```
std::for_each(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [] (const std::unique_ptr<Tank>& tank) {
  // using tank...
});
```

Либо если необходимо использовать именно указанное лямбда-выражение, то проще сделать так:

```
for (auto& tank : v) {
  researchRespawns(*tank);
}
```

Можно немного извернуться и сделать даже так:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [researchRespawns] (std::unique_ptr<Tank>& tank) {
  researchRespawns(*tank);
});
```

Comment: Только первый вариант не работает(

Comment: Какая ошибка у вас?

Comment: cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::unique_ptr<UserTank,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'const std::unique_ptr<Tank,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &'

Comment: Ну так приведение типов и не будет работать в данном случае: вы используете умный указатель на UserTank и пытаетесь передать его как умный указатель на Entity.

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо